# Kafka Consumer test always fail

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am trying perform performance test for my Kafka Cluster but it always fails . Here are the logs

bin/kafka-consumer-perf-test.sh --topic test --broker-list localhost:9092,localhost:9093,localhost:9094  --messages 500 --timeout 1000000

start.time, end.time, data.consumed.in.MB, MB.sec, data.consumed.in.nMsg, nMsg.sec, rebalance.time.ms, fetch.time.ms, fetch.MB.sec, fetch.nMsg.sec

WARNING: Exiting before consuming the expected number of messages: timeout (1000000 ms) exceeded. You can use the --timeout option to increase the timeout.
2020-07-02 17:23:52:304, 2020-07-02 17:40:32:625, 0.0000, 0.0000, 11, 0.0110, 1593690832494, -1593689832173, -0.0000, -0.0000

Whenever i increase timeout option and decrease message parameter then also i did not get results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the output, it seems that your topic only has 11 records produced, so the  tool cannot consume 500 records but has to choose to time out.

If you are only annoyed with the warning, try the command below:

```
> bin/kafka-consumer-perf-test.sh --topic test \
--broker-list localhost:9092,localhost:9093,localhost:9094 \
--messages 11 --timeout 1000000
```